# accessing row value in neo4j with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, object, syntax, neo4j

This is probably more a fundamental PHP syntax question than a neo4j question.

I am using Codeigniter/PHP and Neo4j. Here I am running a query which returns one node:

```
$cypher = "MATCH (a:Address) WHERE a.address = '".$address."' RETURN a, ID(a) as id LIMIT 1";

$res = $this->neo->execute_query($cypher);
```

Now I want to access the "id" from that node:

```
foreach($res as $r){
    $adr_id = $r["id"];     
}
```

There must be a cleaner way of doing this. I tried:

```
$adr_id = $res->rows["id"]
```

But it raises an error because rows is a protected property. Anyone who could point me in the right way?

Comment: what is the CI library you use for neo4j ?

Comment: https://github.com/asfandahmed/Neo4jPHP-lib-for-CodeIgniter